# When do we say "an idea to do something" and "an idea of doing something"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I guess we say "**an idea to do something**" when "**the idea has not appeared yet**"

and we say "**an idea of doing something**" when "**the idea has already appeared**"

For example, "**can you come up with an idea to catch the rabbit?**" versus "**I came up with an idea of catching the rabbit**".

But I am not sure.

When do we say "**an idea to do something**" and "**an idea of doing something**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the distinction which you make exists. I would use **an idea for doing something** to mean a possible way of solving a problem, and **the idea of doing something** for a completely new idea.

> I've got an idea for catching the rabbit.
>
> I had the idea of buying a rabbit, which could live in a hutch in the garden.